# AMS1117-3.3 Voltage Conversion: LED Behavior Issues

Tags: voltage, led, dc-dc-converter

I am utilizing the AMS1117-3.3 voltage regulator to convert a 5V input to 3.3V. Following the schematic provided in the datasheet, I have added a couple of LEDs to the circuit.

However, I am encountering an issue where both LEDs illuminate when I connect a 5V source (which is the expected behavior). Surprisingly, even when I connect a 3.3V source from other pins, both LEDs continue to light up.

I am seeking assistance in finding a solution where, when powered by 3.3V, only the 3.3V power LED illuminates.

[image: Schematic]
Is there a way to achieve this without experiencing significant voltage drops? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Let me check if I got it right: If you apply 3.3V **externally** across VO and GND terminals **without applying 5V across VBUS**, D6 lights up. Correct? Sorry if I couldn't understand correctly.

Comment: Yes. When connecting 3.3V, both light up. However, this should not happen.

Comment: If the rest of the circuit will be happy with, say, 3.1V then you can add a low Vf diode (e.g. Schottky) from VO pin to 3.3V. This will prevent current flow back into the regulator when an external power is applied.

Comment: Why are you connecting 3.3v to what should be the output of a voltage regulator?

Comment: @HandyHowie I saw a few circuits having MCU in which the programmer provides 3.3V and this goes directly across the output of a linear regulator. So the OP's could be a possibly similar scenario.

Comment: @HandyHowie, the 5V Voltage Supply comes from an USB-Connector. It is also Possible to power the stm32 with 3.3V, which I want to be the case, when using the sim-programmer.

Comment: What do you call a significant voltage drop, and what is insignificant? Also no matter what you do on the regulator input, you are not supposed to parallel the  regulator output with another power supply. In your case, it will leak current to input side, possibly back-feeding and damaging your PC or whatever is the 5V source.

Answer (score 1):

You could also place a diode on the regulator's input side to prevent the input LED from lighting up from any leakage currents. Just be sure to move the cap to the regulator's input pin side. The TI version [(LM1117) datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1117.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1686808388157) shows a similar example when using two regulators in a battery backup arrangement, (see figure 9-7).  Also be aware that if passing a high current you could come close to the regulator's drop-out voltage requirements, so a Schottky type diode will be best to use in this case.